# Betting system won't seem to process the user input correctly, how can this be improved?

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a game of craps in which the player has a virtual 'wallet' to gamble with. I've gotten to the user input part and it's not going as planned.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import random     
import sys
money = "500"
 
# start the game
a = input("Hello travler, to start the game, please type 'yes'. If you are not ready to begin your journey, type 'no' ")
if a.lower() == "no":
    sys.exit()
else:
    print("Welcome")
    print("Hold on... I'm missing something,")
name = input("What is your name, traveler?: ")
print("Welcome,", (name)) 

# those who need instructions can ask for it,
# others can start the game directly.
a = input("Welcome to a game that'll determine the rest of your life. Do you need instructions? (yes) or (no)? \n")
 
if a.lower() == "yes":
    print('''1. the player will roll two six sided dice. the sum of the two dice is the player's number for the round.
2. rolling a 7 or an 11 as your first roll win you the game, but be weary, a 2, 3, or 12 automatically causes the player to lose. no more game for you. If a 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10 are rolled on this first roll, that number becomes the 'point.'
3. the fated player continues to roll the two dice again until one of two things occur: either they roll the 'point' again, causing them to win the game; or they roll a 7, causing them to be doomed to the eternals.''')
 
elif a.lower() == "no":
    print("may luck be with you on this fateful day,", name)

print("You will start off with 500 pieces of luck, if you leave this game with over 1000 pieces of luck, you will be fated for sucsess. On the other hand, should you drop below 0 peices of luck, you will find yourself in debt to the universe, a misfortune that few recover from.")
print("You currently have", money, "luck to spare")

# betting time
while True:
  bet = input("How much luck do you wish to bet? ")
  if bet.isdigit() is True:
    if money > bet:
      print("Bet accepted")
  if bet.isdigit() is True:
      if bet > money:
        print("How unfortunate, you do not have the luck to make this bet.")
  elif bet.isdigit() is False:
    print ("Sorry, luck can only be quantitated in number values.")
  # if you bet higher than your money, it wont allow you to bet within after that.
```

The code below the line `# betting time` is where I am hitting my head over.

I need the code to do the following:

- check if the user input is in fact a number, if it's not a number, make them enter a new input
- if the user input is a number, determine if it is within the amount they have in their 'wallet' (if not, make them input a new number)
- if the number is within the amount in their 'wallet' *and* is a digit, give the user the option to "roll dice" triggering the game to start.

If they win, they need to be granted double what they bet, if they lose, they need to lose the amount they bet. The wallet will need to update after each play, giving the user the option to play again with their updated wallet (so if they bet 50 and win, their new balance will be 550. The process continues until the user either reaches 1000 or 0, causing the game to end either way.)

Comment: What is the error or problem you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

For checking if the user's bet is a number use the .isnumeric() function on your bet like:

```
bet.isnumeric()
```

to do the second thing you needed help with you could do:

```
if bet < wallet: blah blah blah elif 
bet > wallet: print("You do not enough money")
```

around like that it with actual good syntax

to do dice you could use the random.randint() function like this:

```
random.randint(1,6)
```

I hope that helps!